# 5V to 3.3V LD1117 voltage regulator design

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am using two 5V 1W voltage sources in parallel and I want to regulate the output to 3.3V using an LD1117. I need help calculating the R2 value for the LD1117.

I have read the datasheet linked below but I find it confusing. How do I calculate the value for R2, given that R1 is 120 Ohm?

I know it is described in the datasheet but I do not understand Vref.

[image]

<sup>Source: [LD1117 Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ld1117.pdf)</sup>

Comment: If you know how LM317 works, this part is essentially the very same thing, using the same ref 1.25V. Just lower dropout voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vref is a voltage reference inside the IC. It fixes the voltage between OUT and the ADJ pin to 1.25 V, regardless of Vin. You can use Vref to manipulate the voltage on the ADJ pin through the feedback network provided by R1 and R2.

For regulation, you should use the formula:

`Vout = Vref (1 + R2/R1)`

where Vref is 1.25 V and R1 is 120 Ω (or something between 100 Ω and 200 Ω)

For example, if you set R1=120 Ω and R2=240 Ω you will get the following output voltage:

```
Vout = 1.25(1+240/120) = 3.75 V
```

The second part of the long formula in the datasheet can be ignored, as it explains, because Iadj is in the order of microamps, so very small.

So, with ADJ tied to GND you would get 1.25 V in Vout. But with the voltage divider you force a higher value in Vout that, once divided, matches with the 1.25 V difference between both pins. It's a feedback system to increase Vout and it doesn't depend on Vin, because of the internal absolute voltage reference.

Answer (score 1):

It reads in the first lines of text that that there is a voltage reference is 1.25V between output and adjust pins. That is the Vref in the formula and marked into the circuit diagram.

Rearrange the formula to calculate R2.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Required Vout=3.3V

Fixed reference voltage (VREF) is= 1.25V

If we substitute into the equation

A=R2

B=R1

R2=(41*R1)/25

Substitute a value between a few kohms for R2 and solve the equation.
Find the  resistor values that provide this ratio from the E 12 series of preferred numbers.So you can find these resistor values from digikey or from an electronics shop

R2=1150 ohm=1.15kohm

R1=698 ohm

in this case Vout=1.25 *(1+(1150/698))=3.30945 V

Comment: This does answer the question stated but unfortunately does not address the OP's comment *"but I do not understand Vref"*. I'd say that's more central to their confusion and need explaining in detail, rather than simply applying the equation practically which is currently all this answer covers.

Comment: R1 being 698 ohms will be too small current if there is no other load. With no other load the regulator can output too high voltage and damage an IC with overvoltage.

Comment: @Justme So should R1 be a smaller value?

Comment: @Electronx Yes, it should be according to data sheet suggestions, or if not, the limitations of not using data sheet values must be understood. You can use much higher resistances if you always draw enough current into load and take the adjust pin current into account.

Comment: "R1  is normally fixed to 120 Ω. From Figure 9 we obtain"
If we accept the R1 value as 120, the R2 value becomes 196.8 ohms. But isn't this note  "In normal application R2  value is in the range of few kΩ, so the R2  x IADJ product could notbe considered in the VOUT calculation; then the above expression becomes"  opposite? because it does not happen in the kiloohm range.In this case, it is more accurate to use the first equations. am I wrong?

Comment: @Justme oh u are right 
Minimum load current must be at least 5 mA.

Comment: @Electronx,  regarding "in the range of few kΩ" I think that it means that anyway Iadj is in the order of microamps, so you can ignore that part of the formula.  1KΩ, 2KΩ or 0.5KΩ makes not a significant difference.  Anyway the datasheet is indeed not very clear.

Comment: Minimum load current is an important factor. So what @Justme said is true.The minimum desired output current is 2 to 5 mA. 550 ohms (3.3/6mA) can be put on the output as a dummy load, or by using lower adjustment resistors, the minimum load current can be flowed using lower resistors without using an extra resistor.

Comment: The R2 value is not that relevant as it sets the output voltage with R1, but the more current goes through R1 and R2, the less will the adjustment pin current affect the result. For example, if you use R1 of 240 ohms, that sets about 5.2mA current, and the adjustment current will add 0.12mA so that always adds higher voltage by 2.3% regardless of which voltage you want with any R2 value. With 120 ohm R1, the error is only 1.25%. So anyway it adds up to R2, even it R2 is just few hundred ohms to set low output voltages.